# The await sleep function changes my code sorting behavior

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add merge sort to my algorithm visualization project and I have got a weird problem...
When I add await sleep(any number) the bars in the HTML page do not sort correctly but when I comment only that line (await sleep(any number)) the sorting goes fine! Any ideas why this is happening.
(the commented lines are the problem)

Github link to the website: https://github.com/Marwan-Ezzat-Mohamed/AlgorthimVisualization (without the bug and no animation)

You can simply see what happens when I uncomment the commented code in the function below here:https://marwan-ezzat-mohamed.github.io/algovis/index

```
async function merge(a, low, m, high) {
  var i, j, k;
  var temp = [];
  var len = m - low;
  console.log(len, 'arr: ', a);
  let bars = Array.from(document.getElementById('addbarshere').children);
  let animationspeed = Number(
    document.getElementById('animation_speed').value
  );
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bars[i].style.backgroundColor=red;
    temp[i] = a[low + i];
  }
  i = 0;
  j = m;
  k = low;
  while (i < len && j < high) {
    let animationspeed = Number(
      document.getElementById('animation_speed').value
    );
    if (temp[i] <= a[j]) {
      bars[k].style.height = temp[i]+'px';
      bars[k].style.backgroundColor=yellow;
      //await sleep(animationspeed);
      bars[k].style.backgroundColor=blue;
      a[k++] = temp[i++];
    } else {
      bars[k].style.height = bars[j].style.height;
      bars[k].style.backgroundColor=yellow;
      //await sleep(animationspeed);
      bars[k].style.backgroundColor=blue;
      a[k++] = a[j++];
    }
  }
  while (i < len) {
    let animationspeed = Number(
      document.getElementById('animation_speed').value
    );
    bars[k].style.height = temp[i]+'px';
    bars[k].style.backgroundColor=yellow;
    //await sleep(100);
    bars[k].style.backgroundColor=blue;
    a[k++] = temp[i++];
  }
}

function mergesort(a, low, high) {
  if (high - low > 1) {
    var m = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
    mergesort(a, low, m);
    mergesort(a, m, high);
    merge(a, low, m, high);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just ran your code from Github locally and the "Merge sort" button is animating.
What is exactly is going wrong?

Comment: There are no animation colors to be shown because it happens so fast that you can't even see it...so to add the color for a switching effect  I have to use the sleep function so you can actually see what's happening. when I use the await sleep function the sort doesn't work correctly for some reason.
you can see what I mean if you uncomment the commented lines in the function above or see this link:https://marwan-ezzat-mohamed.github.io/algovis/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a race condition in your code. Your merge function is asynchronous and you are calling it without await in mergesort function. This means that when the sleeps are reached, the execution is not blocked it just continues outside of that merge function invocation. In the end, all of the merge functions invocations are executing "at the same time" instead of one after the other and they produce gibberish when working over the same list.

To solve this you have to guarantee that the merges are executed synchronously. For that purpose, you can convert your mergesort function in an async function too and use await on merge and mergesort calls to force them to execute synchronously. This is all you have to change (in addition to uncommenting your sleeps).

```
async function mergesort(a, low, high) {
  if (high - low > 1) {
    var m = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
    await mergesort(a, low, m);
    await mergesort(a, m, high);
    await merge(a, low, m, high);
  }
}
```

Note: Actually, they aren't all doing things at the same time. One is doing things while the others are sleeping. They are just scheduled in a non-synchronous way and yield the execution instead of blocking.